# Create a dataframe column from a lookup matrix

Tags: python, pandas, lookup-tables

I have the following df:

| idx | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

I want to create a new column based on a looking up the `value` for a given row in conjunction with a `constant` value in the following matrix:

| x | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.3 | 0.4 |
| 2 | 0.3 | 1 | 0.2 |
| 3 | 0.4 | 0.2 | 1 |

So if `constant` == 1 then the resulting dataframe would look like:

| idx | value | lookup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.3 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.4 |

Existing answers I've seen reference:

1. [`pandas.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) which is deprecated
2. [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) which aren't really scalable if the lookup matrix gets large

I think there might be a solution around [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) but I'm struggling to get my head around it. Would anyone have any suggestions?

I should probably mention that speed is really important so a vectorised solution would be preferable.

To replicate:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"value": [1, 2, 3]})
df_lookup = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[1, 2, 3],
    data={1: [1, 0.3, 0.4], 2: [0.3, 1, 0.2], 3: [0.4, 0.2, 0.1]}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can directly map the row to `value` column

```py
constant = 1
df['lookup'] = df['value'].map(df_lookup.loc[constant, :])
```

```
print(df)

   value  lookup
0      1     1.0
1      2     0.3
2      3     0.4
```

Comment: Thanks. This definitely works but I'm not sure if `map` takes advantage of vectorization?

Comment: @Jossy For the speed case, it will be much slower than vectorization.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your life easy and the value column in df is non-repeating, then you could set it as the index and simply use loc.

```
constant = 1
df['mapped'] = df_lookup.loc[df.index, constant]
```

Which gives me :

```
   value  lookup
1      1     1.0
2      2     0.3
3      3     0.4
```

However, if it is repeating, this would not work. Then you could use .merge such as :

```
constant = 1
df = df.merge(df_lookup[constant], left_on='value', right_index=True)
```